# Finite-state machine design for lexing

Tags: c++, c++14

The problem. To represent a finite-state automaton capable of recognizing and extracting a token from a character stream.

This is my quick attempt at it. I've included both the class definition and an example usage below.

I would appreciate tips on simplifying or optimizing the design and everything as a whole.

```
#include <string>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <utility>
#include <iterator>
#include <vector>
#include <tuple>

template<typename State,
    typename String = std::string, 
    typename StringIterator = std::string::iterator, // might use custom utf8 adapter
>
class FiniteStateMachine
{
public:
    using state_type = State;
    using string_type = String;
    using string_iterator = StringIterator;
    using function_type = bool(*)(typename std::iterator_traits<string_iterator>::value_type);

private:
    const state_type initial;
    state_type current; // reset to initial after every run()

    // one state may transition to many states hence the vector
    // vector's elements are <function returning bool, new state if true>
    std::unordered_map<state_type, std::vector<std::pair<function_type, state_type>>> input;

public:
    explicit FiniteStateMachine(const state_type& state)
        : initial{ state }, current{ state }
    {}

    FiniteStateMachine(const state_type& state,
                       std::initializer_list<std::tuple<state_type, function_type, state_type>> ilist)
        : initial{ state }, current { state }
    {
        for (auto&& i : ilist) {
            input[std::get<0>(i)].emplace_back(std::get<1>(i), std::get<2>(i));
        }
    }

    void add_function(state_type in_state, function_type fun, state_type out_state) {
        input[in_state].emplace_back(fun, out_state);
    }

    bool run(string_type& str, string_type& extracted)
    {
        string_type res;
        for (string_iterator first{ str.begin() }; first != string_iterator{ str.end() }; ++first)
        {
            auto search = input.find(current);
            if (search == input.end()) {
                return false;
            }
            else
            {
                bool fin = true;
                for (auto&& f : search->second)
                {
                    if (f.first(*first))
                    {
                        fin = false;

                        current = f.second;
                        res += *first;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                if (fin) {
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        current = initial;

        str.erase(0, res.size());
        return res.size() ? extracted = std::move(res), true : false;
    }
};
```

And usage:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cctype>

enum class State
{
    initial,
    secondary
};

bool NonDigit(char c) { return std::isalpha(c) || c == '_'; }
bool Digit(char c) { return std::isdigit(c); }
bool Space(char c) { return std::isspace(c); }

int main()
{
    std::string input = "int main int _asf char 23_asf, double _asf23";

    FiniteStateMachine<State> identifier{
        State::initial,
        { { State::initial, [](auto c) { return NonDigit(c); }, State::secondary },
        { State::secondary, [](auto c) { return NonDigit(c) || Digit(c); }, State::secondary } }
    };

    FiniteStateMachine<State> space{ State::initial };

    space.add_function(State::initial, [](auto c) { return Space(c); }, State::initial);

    while (!input.empty())
    {
        std::string word;
        if (identifier.run(input, word)) {
            std::cout << word;
        }
        else if (space.run(input, word)) {
            std::cout << word;
        }
        else 
        {
            std::cout << "\nError!\n";
            break;
        }
    }
    std::cin.get();
}
```

Comment: Arguably, `StringIterator` in the template definition should have the default argument `typename StringIterator = typename String::iterator` to enable instanciation without an explicit argument for types different than `std::string`.